# SVG cut off in Firefox.

Tags: firefox, svg

i need help with this SVG code below that is beeing cut off in Firefox only. Chrome, IE work fine.
I tried several solutions already with no luck.
This SVG was exported from illustrator.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 13.4 30.3" style="enable-background:new 0 0 13.4 30.3;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{clip-path:url(#SVGID_3_);}
 .st1{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);fill:#76BE5A;}
 
  .st2{clip-path:url(#SVGID_6_);fill:none;stroke:#76BE5A;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g>
 <g>
  <defs>
   <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="-0.6" y="0.3" width="14" height="30"/>
  </defs>
  <defs>
   <path id="SVGID_2_" d="M4.6,2c0.2-1.1,1.2-1.9,2.2-1.7c1,0.2,1.7,1.2,1.5,2.3L8.1,3.8C8,4.9,7,5.6,6,5.5c-1-0.2-1.7-1.2-1.5-2.3
    L4.6,2"/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="SVGID_3_">
   <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="SVGID_4_" class="st0">
   <use xlink:href="#SVGID_2_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
  </clipPath>
  <rect x="-0.6" y="-4.8" class="st1" width="14" height="15.3"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <defs>
   <rect id="SVGID_5_" x="-0.6" y="0.3" width="14" height="30"/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="SVGID_6_">
   <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path class="st2" d="M12.4,17.5c-0.1-0.1-1.8-4.4-1.8-4.4L8.7,7.5L3.3,8.4l-0.5,4.7l-1.6,5.2 M5.1,16.6l1.8,12.7 M12.4,29.3
   l-2.9-5.9l-0.8-5.9l-3.7-0.9"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Thank you

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox. Maybe add 2 images, one showing the correct view, and one showing the cut off one, so its more obvious where to look.